# Normalizing plots in matlab

Tags: matlab, normalization

so I'm pretty new to Matlab. I have some .txt files that are tab delimited with wavelengths in the first column and intensities in the second column. I need to normalize these plots to put all of them on the same graph and compare the peak wavelengths. I tried looking it up and it looks like the normc() function might be what I want, but apparently it isn't included in my student version of Matlab. Is there any other/better way to do this? So far all I have for sure is:

```
blueled = load('blu_led.txt');
greenled = load('green_led.txt');
orangeled = load('orange_led.txt');
orangeredled = load('orangered_led.txt');
redled = load('red_led.txt');
irled = load('ir_led.txt');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start with the `max` and `min` functions (see the docs) and then use something like this:

```
mini=min(blueled);
blueled=blueled-mini;
maxi=max(blueled);
blueled=blueled/maxi;
```

Now the `blueled` is between 0 and 1.
If you want to norm all the variables, use `max` of the maxima and `min` of the minima.

**Important: The code above will work on one column of the data. You should use it on blueled(:,1) if you want to treat just the first column. Otherwise the output would not be a scalar but a vector of maxima of the columns.** Of course, it's handy to treat both columns at once using the first and the second component of the vector but one should be aware of it.

Comment: This doesn't maintain the scale though. For instance: >> blueled = [5 3 4]

blueled =

     5     3     4

>> mini=min(blueled);
blueled=blueled-mini;
maxi=max(blueled);
blueled=blueled./maxi;
>> blueled

blueled =

    1.0000         0    0.5000

Comment: OK, you're right, I was using that for a slightly different purpose. Use just `maxi`-part and then it should look like [1 0.6 0.8]. Is that it?